# How to add a gradient to an arc in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, gradient, android-canvas

I'm trying to create an Arc in jetpack compose and apply a sweep gradient to it but i'm having trouble making the gradient color start from the beggining of the arc(left) to the end of it(right)

this is my arc and gradient

```
val gradient = Brush.sweepGradient(
    colors = listOf(
        Color.Green,
        Color.Yellow,
        Color.Red,
        )
)

drawArc(
    brush = gradient,
    startAngle = -230f,
    sweepAngle = 280f,
    useCenter = false,
    style = Stroke(4.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
    size = Size(64.dp.toPx(), 64.dp.toPx())
)
```

I'm trying to achieve something like a speedometer with an arrow pointing, starting from green -> yellow -> red.
Right now it starts with yellow green yellow red and green again.

I know i'm supposed to give it a center Offset to the gradient but I can't figure out which one. I tried multiple combinations.

Do you have any tips please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [version of sweepGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Brush#sweepGradient(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset)) that takes `colorStops`

The color stops are defined as a fraction `[0f, 1f]` of the circle, starting at 3 o'clock. To figure out the fractions you want, you should measure your wanted points in clockwise degrees starting from 3 o'clock, then mapping them in the 0, 1 space.

Example: for the `startAngle` you have -230 degrees, which is 130 deg (`n`) in the color stop frame of reference. To get the fraction you then do

```
f = n / 360
```

With your angles, some rough values that work are

```
    val gradient = Brush.sweepGradient(
        colorStops = arrayOf(
            0.3f to Color.Red,
            0.36f to Color.Green,
            0.75f to Color.Yellow,
            1f to Color.Red,
        ),
    )
```